# Shopware Docker Can't login into Docker MySQL database

Tags: mysql, docker, shopware

Hi i installed Shopware developer project like [here](https://github.com/shopware/platform) and it works fine but i can't login into database. I am getting error if i tried ./psh.phar administration:watch or ./psh.phar administration:build ->

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:

  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddr  
  esses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known      


In PDOConnection.php line 31:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodena  
  me nor servname provided, or not known                                       


In PDOConnection.php line 27:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodena  
  me nor servname provided, or not known                                       


In PDOConnection.php line 27:

  PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename   
  nor servname provided, or not known                                          



Execution aborted, a subcommand failed!
```

I tried also login in adminer with credentials what are in docker-compose.yml and i am getting same error. Do you have any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I had to first time start `./psh.phar docker:ssh` and then follow commannd `./psh.phar administration:build`. Now everythink working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

[The Docker Hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) for MySQL has many useful information on how to use MySQL with Docker.

In your docker-compose/Dockerfile filess make sure to provide the environment-variables required by MySQL, e.g.: `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`.

Also, make sure to read Shopware documentation to make sure you are providing all the required values in your docker-compose/Dockerfile files.

Answer (score 0):

In my docker-compose.yml i have this enviroment configuration

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
MYSQL_USER: app
MYSQL_PASSWORD: app
```

If i launch my app on `localhost:8000` evereythink working so it's mein that app can log into database but from console or adminer i can't. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look weather the mysql container started. You can use `docker ps -a` for it.

If not, use `docker logs ${containerId}` for showing information why it not started.

Also post a ./psh.phar docker:start here.